# how to rename video file in sd card in android

Tags: android

```
public void reNameFileName(String filePath, String newFilename) {
        String path = filePath;
        String filename = path.substring( path.lastIndexOf( "/" ) + 1 );
        File oldfile = new File(filename);
        File newfile = new File(newFilename,".mp4");
        /*oldfile.renameTo(newfile);*/
        if (oldfile.renameTo(newfile)) {
            Toast.makeText( VideoPlayActvity.this, "Rename succesful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText( VideoPlayActvity.this, "Rename failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    }
```

this is my code for rename file i am able to get old file name and try to replace it by new file name then each time it goes fail condition please suggest me where am doing mistake.

Comment: do you have write permissions? Which version of Android you use?

Comment: Android 6.1 Marshamllow

Comment: `do you have write permissions?`

Comment: also as for 6.1 - did you request runtime permissions?

Comment: yes i have given write permission in android manifest file

Comment: `did you request runtime permissions?`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: no i dint request run time permisson

Comment: can u please tell me how to apply runtime permssion

Comment: you can use search for that. have you tried searching among thousands of questions about the runtime permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you given permission to the app in manifest file to write to external sd card? If not, like this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also, you can get the file storage directory with the following.

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Then, to implement the whole thing

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File first = new File(sdcard,"first.txt"); 
File rename = new File(sdcard,"rename.txt");
first.renameTo(rename);
```

Because the file path should never be hardcoded into the program, but the above function should be used

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: this also not working same thing i did but still same issue